# cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested not getting true in rolling upgrade for service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a state full service which is scanning a reliable collection and performing some operation on the same. The code in the RunAsync is as following:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                var cacheItemsWithExpiration = await this.cacheStore.GetAllCacheItemsWithExpiration(); // Call to reliable collection

                // some processing on cacheItemsWithExpiration
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.telemetryHelper.TrackException(ex); // Telemetry logging
            }
        }
```

Now during rolling upgrade GetAllCacheItemsWithExpiration methods throws an error **"Primary State Manager is currently not readable"**.

Now as per the code written, after the exception the while loop should exit as I suppose upgrade will send the cancellation. But somehow it stuck in that loop and keep logging in the exceptions.

I see the following message in Service Fabric explorer:

[image]

Comment: Just to add this happens intermittently while releasing i.e. not with every release.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the screenshot, the error is happening in the secondary replica, by the message, looks like it was trying to switch roles, where a primary become a secondary and vice versa.

The **SwapPrimary** reconfiguration happens when a upgrade have to put down instances to bring a new version, and when it happens on the primary replica, one of the secondary is promoted to Primary.

As you can see, it is just a warning, what is likely to happen is your code is taking too long to finish between loops until you check again for the cancellation, maybe the `GetAllCacheItemsWithExpiration()` is taking too long or the code right after it is still processing when the swap happens.

You can try to:

- Check if the cancellation token is being correctly cancelled
- Check for the cancellation inside your method `GetAllCacheItemsWithExpiration()`
- Check for the cancellation after returning the method
- Check everywhere that might cause the process to hang for a while

In last case, you might want to implement an override of `OnChangeRoleAsync(ReplicaRole newRole, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` from your stateful service to track change of roles, please see more details [here](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle#stateful-service-primary-swaps)

[See this docs to understand more about the Reconfiguration in Azure Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-reconfiguration)

Comment: Yes I am taking care of cancellation token. Just to provide more clarification, the following is happening:  1. During upgrade  GetAllCacheItemsWithExpiration throw an exception "System.Fabric.FabricNotReadableException"  2. It goes to catch block and logs the exception  3. Hit the while loop condition where it checks the cancellationRequestedFlag, which seems to returning false and that makes it to go inside loop again.  4. Again GetAllCacheItemsWithExpiration is called and the above sequence kept repeating.  Ultimatley I have to delete the services in ASF explorer.

Comment: Please NOTE:: This does not happen always, I noticed it twice in a week (We do 2 deployments per day), but when it happens it stuck in the state infinitely and then we have to delete it ultimately. The reason this is scary that if it happens in PROD we need to ask for a downtime as we have to then delete the service and then deploy it, which surely defeat our purpose of using service fabric (Zero downtime).

Comment: In this case the reason seems to be the token not being cancelled, are you using the token they provide or you are using your own? Are you processing the data on all replicas or just on the Primary?
Can you override the `OnChangeRoleAsync` and see if the cancellation is being cancelled?

Comment: 1. Yes I am using the same token recieved as parameter in RunAsync
2. I am not sure how to identify if I am processing the data in all replicas or primary. Is there a configuration?
3. I have override OnChangeRoleAsync and logging the cancellationtoken status. Will let you know when the issue will again surface.
4. Also the telemetry s showing that cancellationtoken state is false when the above scenario occurs.